# UPDATE random result numbers to same numbers result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i'm trying to update column from another table which means :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM creature WHERE map = 389;
```

This SQL will give me this result :

```
11323
11322
11324
11520
11321
```

What i want is to update creature_template lootid = 11323 where entry = 11323 so it goes as following :

```
UPDATE creature_template SET lootid = 11323 WHERE entry = 11323
```

I have tried this :

```
UPDATE creature_template SET lootid = 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM creature
    WHERE map = 389) WHERE lootid = entry;
```

I'm sure it's incorrect simply it's not logic but couldn't find the logical answer for this.

Even REPLACE could work instead of UPDATE so any will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `JOIN` with `UPDATE` :

```
UPDATE creature_template ct 
     INNER JOIN creature c
     ON c.id = ct.entry 
     SET ct.lootid  = c.id
WHERE c.map = 389;
```